# Selenium. Chrome v74. Freezing after cookies deletion

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After updating Chrome to 74.0.3729.131, problems are appeared.
Using webdrivermanager 3.4.0 for managing chromedriver.

```
public class UiTestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static String url;
    @BeforeTest()
    public void initialize() {
        url = "http://example.com"
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

public class LoginTest extends UiTestBase {
    private WebDriverWait wait;
    private SignInPage loginPage;

    @BeforeMethod()
    public void openLoginPage() {
        System.out.println("Delete cookies");
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        System.out.println("Add wait");
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        loginPage = new SignInPage(driver);
        driver.get(url);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(loginPage.getLoginButton()));
    }

    @Test()
    public void Login1() {
        loginPage.makeLogin("user", "pass");
        loginPage.getLoginButton().click();
    }

    @Test()
    public void Login2() { 
        loginPage.makeLogin("user", "123456");
        loginPage.getLoginButton().click();
    }
}
```

Login1 - successfully passed.
While execution Login2, I see that method openLoginPage is running forever.
In console output I see only "Remove cookies" and that's all.
I don't see "Add wait".

On Chrome 73 using same code there are no such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the Webdriver manager downloaded the latest and correct version. Did you trigger a download?

If you have the latest version, maybe a regression was introduced and you need to file a defect report.

Options:

- Manually download and test the latest driver version: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- Downgrade Chrome and the driver: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792?hl=en
- Ask on the ChromeDriver User Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/chromedriver-users
- File a defect for the ChromeDriver: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list